# Google Maps Geocoder not giving results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps V3 API and using its Geocoder to do reverse geocoding of the point on the map where the user clicks on.

**Load the geocoding function when DOM is fully loaded**

```
$(function() {
reverse_geocode(40.714224,-73.961452);
```

});

**Function that does the reverse geocoding**:

```
function reverse_geocode(lat,lng) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10,-10);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert('asdasd');
        } else {
             alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
```

}

If I call the `reverse_geocode` function when the page first loads, everything works fine and the `alert()` is called.

However, if I call `reverse_geocode()` only when triggered by a rightclick on the map followed by a mouseclick on a div, using the code below, nothing happens! Any idea what went wrong?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
                //some code not shown
                $("#info_rightclick_top").click(function(e) {

                    info_ok_handleclick();
                });
            });


function info_ok_handleclick() {
            $("#info_ok").click(function(e) {
                var lat = marker_search_location.getPosition().lat();
                var lng = marker_search_location.getPosition().lng();
                var latlng = lat + "_" + lng;



                reverse_geocode(10,-10);

                // some code hidden
            });
```

Comment: There are just way too many event handlers here. Your info_ok_handlerclick(). attaches yet another handler so you need to click 3 times before invoking your reverse geocode function. In theory you just need 2 event listeners - 1 for right click (lets say for a function that shows a menu) and a #info_ok handler to do geocoding. your info_ok handler does not need to be wrapped in a function but simply put in a document.ready jquery block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this bellow code you can search a location by keywords.

```
        <?php
         include_once("include/GoogleMap.php");
         include_once("include/JSMin.php");
         $mapcity="India";
         $mapdesc="description about this map";
         $MAP_OBJECT = new GoogleMapAPI(); 
         $MAP_OBJECT->_minify_js = isset($_REQUEST["min"])?FALSE:TRUE;

         $MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByAddress($mapcity,"Map name", $mapdesc);
         $MAP_OBJECT->enableStreetViewControls();
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <?=$MAP_OBJECT->getHeaderJS();?>
        <?=$MAP_OBJECT->getMapJS();?>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?=$MAP_OBJECT->printOnLoad();?>
        <?=$MAP_OBJECT->setMapType(ROADMAP);?>
        <?=$MAP_OBJECT->printMap();?>
        <?=$MAP_OBJECT->printSidebar();?>
        </body>
        </html>
```